# Spoofing hard disk serial number via a driver

Tags: windows, kernel, hard-drive, spoofing

I modified a windows driver that [spoofs hard disk number](https://github.com/lantaoxu/HWIDFaker) by generating a random serial, I modified it to spoof a pre-known serial, now when it get loaded and query for the first time via `wmi` for the serial then it shows the pre-defined serial, but if I query again, it shows an empty string.
The driver implementation:

```
#include <ntifs.h>
#include <Ntdddisk.h>
#include <windef.h>
#include "main.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winapifamily.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <Ntstrsafe.h>

PDRIVER_DISPATCH RealDiskDeviceControl = NULL;
char NumTable[]    = "123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char SpoofedHWID[] = "XYXYXYYYYYXYXXYXYYYXXYYXXXXYYXYYYXYYX\0";
BOOL HWIDGenerated = 0;

char* newDiskId = "WD-WMATV3142957\0";

typedef struct _WIN32_FIND_DATA {
    DWORD    dwFileAttributes;
    FILETIME ftCreationTime;
    FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
    DWORD    nFileSizeHigh;
    DWORD    nFileSizeLow;
    DWORD    dwReserved0;
    DWORD    dwReserved1;
    TCHAR    cFileName[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR    cAlternateFileName[14];
} WIN32_FIND_DATA, *PWIN32_FIND_DATA, *LPWIN32_FIND_DATA;

PDRIVER_OBJECT GetDriverObject(PUNICODE_STRING DriverName)
{
    PDRIVER_OBJECT DrvObject;
    if (NT_SUCCESS(ObReferenceObjectByName(DriverName, 0, NULL, 0, *IoDriverObjectType, KernelMode, NULL, &DrvObject)))
    {
        return DrvObject;
    }

    return NULL;
}




NTSTATUS SpoofSerialNumber(char* serialNumber)
{
    //RtlSecureZeroMemory
    if (!HWIDGenerated)
    {
        HWIDGenerated = 1;
        size_t newDiskIdLen = 0;
        RtlStringCchLengthA(newDiskId, NTSTRSAFE_MAX_CCH, &newDiskIdLen);
        RtlCopyMemory((void*)serialNumber, (void*)newDiskId, ++newDiskIdLen);
    }
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS StorageQueryCompletionRoutine(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp, PVOID Context)
{
    PIO_COMPLETION_ROUTINE OldCompletionRoutine = NULL;
    PVOID OldContext = NULL;
    ULONG OutputBufferLength = 0;
    PSTORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR descriptor = NULL;

    if (Context != NULL)
    {
        REQUEST_STRUCT* pRequest = (REQUEST_STRUCT*)Context;
        OldCompletionRoutine = pRequest->OldRoutine;
        OldContext = pRequest->OldContext;
        OutputBufferLength = pRequest->OutputBufferLength;
        descriptor = pRequest->StorageDescriptor;

        ExFreePool(Context);
    }

    if (FIELD_OFFSET(STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR, SerialNumberOffset) < OutputBufferLength && descriptor->SerialNumberOffset > 0 && descriptor->SerialNumberOffset < OutputBufferLength)
    {
        char* SerialNumber = ((char*)descriptor) + descriptor->SerialNumberOffset;
        size_t SerialNumberLen = 0;
        RtlStringCchLengthA(SerialNumber, NTSTRSAFE_MAX_CCH, &SerialNumberLen);
        RtlSecureZeroMemory(SerialNumber, SerialNumberLen);
        SpoofSerialNumber(SerialNumber);
    }

    if ((Irp->StackCount >(ULONG)1) && (OldCompletionRoutine != NULL))
        return OldCompletionRoutine(DeviceObject, Irp, OldContext);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS SmartCompletionRoutine(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp, PVOID Context)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);

    PIO_COMPLETION_ROUTINE OldCompletionRoutine = NULL;
    PVOID OldContext = NULL;

    if (Context != NULL)
    {
        REQUEST_STRUCT* pRequest = (REQUEST_STRUCT*)Context;
        OldCompletionRoutine = pRequest->OldRoutine;
        OldContext = pRequest->OldContext;
        ExFreePool(Context);
    }

    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED;

    return Irp->IoStatus.Status;
}

NTSTATUS DiskDriverDispatch(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp)
{
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION Io = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

    switch (Io->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode)
    {
    case IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY:
    {
        PSTORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY query = (PSTORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;

        if (query->PropertyId == StorageDeviceProperty)
        {
            Io->Control = 0;
            Io->Control |= SL_INVOKE_ON_SUCCESS;

            PVOID OldContext = Io->Context;
            Io->Context = (PVOID)ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, sizeof(REQUEST_STRUCT));
            REQUEST_STRUCT *pRequest = (REQUEST_STRUCT*)Io->Context;
            pRequest->OldRoutine = Io->CompletionRoutine;
            pRequest->OldContext = OldContext;
            pRequest->OutputBufferLength = Io->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.OutputBufferLength;
            pRequest->StorageDescriptor = (PSTORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;

            Io->CompletionRoutine = (PIO_COMPLETION_ROUTINE)StorageQueryCompletionRoutine;
        }

        break;

    }

    case SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA:
    {
        Io->Control = 0;
        Io->Control |= SL_INVOKE_ON_SUCCESS;

        PVOID OldContext = Io->Context;
        Io->Context = (PVOID)ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, sizeof(REQUEST_STRUCT));
        REQUEST_STRUCT *pRequest = (REQUEST_STRUCT*)Io->Context;
        pRequest->OldRoutine = Io->CompletionRoutine;
        pRequest->OldContext = OldContext;

        Io->CompletionRoutine = (PIO_COMPLETION_ROUTINE)SmartCompletionRoutine;

        break;
    }
    }

    return RealDiskDeviceControl(DeviceObject, Irp);
}

NTSTATUS UnsupportedDispatch(
    _In_ struct _DEVICE_OBJECT *DeviceObject,
    _Inout_ struct _IRP *Irp
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);

    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
    return Irp->IoStatus.Status;
}

NTSTATUS CreateDispatch(
    _In_ struct _DEVICE_OBJECT *DeviceObject,
    _Inout_ struct _IRP *Irp
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);

    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
    return Irp->IoStatus.Status;
}

NTSTATUS CloseDispatch(_In_ struct _DEVICE_OBJECT *DeviceObject, _Inout_ struct _IRP *Irp
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);

    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
    return Irp->IoStatus.Status;
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_  struct _DRIVER_OBJECT *DriverObject, _In_  PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
        NTSTATUS        status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

        UNICODE_STRING diskDrvName;
        RtlInitUnicodeString(&diskDrvName, L"\\Driver\\disk");

        PDRIVER_OBJECT diskDrvObj = GetDriverObject(&diskDrvName);

        RealDiskDeviceControl = diskDrvObj->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL];

        diskDrvObj->DriverInit = &DriverEntry;
        diskDrvObj->DriverStart = (PVOID)DriverObject;
        diskDrvObj->DriverSize = (ULONG)RegistryPath;
        diskDrvObj->FastIoDispatch = NULL;
        diskDrvObj->DriverStartIo = NULL;
        diskDrvObj->DriverUnload = NULL;

        /*for (ULONG t = 0; t <= IRP_MJ_MAXIMUM_FUNCTION; t++)
            diskDrvObj->MajorFunction[t] = &UnsupportedDispatch;*/

        diskDrvObj->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL] = &DiskDriverDispatch;
        /*diskDrvObj->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] = &CreateDispatch;
        diskDrvObj->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE] = &CloseDispatch;*/

        return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
NTSTATUS SpoofSerialNumber(char* serialNumber)
{
    //RtlSecureZeroMemory
    if (!HWIDGenerated)
    {
        HWIDGenerated = 1;
```

There's your issue, I'm not sure if your using this for game-cheating purposes but if you are this is detected on all major anticheats (maybe not eac but def BE). The reason it only spoofs once is due to the very unusual code in this driver which makes it only spoof once (defeating the whole purpose of hooking disks dispatch routine), this is hwidfaker from github which is not a great example to see how spoofers work its quite simple and unorganized (its pasted).